# Update React Component When Using react-responsive-tabs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, laravel

In my react app when I make a serverside update I return a response which I use to update the state of the parent component. But for my components where I use react-responsive-tabs they don't get updated. 
Here's my react code:

```
import React, {Component, Fragment} from 'react';
import ReactCSSTransitionGroup from 'react-addons-css-transition-group';

import PageTitle from '../../../Layout/AppMain/PageTitle';

import {
    faAngleUp,
    faAngleDown,
    faCommentDots,
    faBullhorn,
    faBusinessTime,
    faCog
} from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';

import {FontAwesomeIcon} from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';

import Tabs from 'react-responsive-tabs';

import Roles from './Roles';
import Priviledges from './Priviledges';

export default class Apage extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            api: this.props.api,
            session: this.props.session
        }
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        this.tabsContent = [
            {
                title: 'Roles',
                content: <Roles api={this.state.api} session={this.state.session} />
            },
            {
                title: 'Priviledges',
                content: <Priviledges api={this.state.api} session={this.state.session} />
            }
        ];
    }

    getTabs() {
        return this.tabsContent.map((tab, index) => ({
            title: tab.title,
            getContent: () => tab.content,
            key: index,
        }));
    }

    onTabChange = selectedTabKey => {
        this.setState({ selectedTabKey });
    };


    render() {

        return (
            <Fragment>
                    <PageTitle
                        heading="Roles & Priviledges"
                        subheading=""
                        icon="lnr-apartment icon-gradient bg-mean-fruit"
                    />
                    <Tabs selectedTabKey={this.state.selectedTabKey} onChange={this.onTabChange} tabsWrapperClass="body-tabs body-tabs-layout" transform={false} showInkBar={true} items={this.getTabs()}/>
            </Fragment>
        )
    }
}
```

I have tried using this within my `<Roles />` tag:

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
   return nextProps.session!= this.props.session;
}
```

but I couldn't get it to work for me. Any clue?
I'm running my React JS within laravel using laravel-mix. I actually intend to update a dropdown whenever I submit a form using `setState`. I've done this many other times when I use React JSas a REST API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using socket IO to trigger a `setSate` within my component after a response comes from the server. Although i'd prefer something neater.

Answer (score 0):

You need to onChange like this - `onChange={() => this.onTabChange()}`

see below-

```
<Tabs onChange={() => this.onTabChange()} selectedTabKey={this.state.selectedTabKey}  tabsWrapperClass="body-tabs body-tabs-layout" transform={false} showInkBar={true} items={this.getTabs()}/>
```

Comment: This answer is a bit out of the question. Not working.

Comment: you used onChange={() => this.onTabChange() ??

Comment: yes. It didn't work and if i open a modal i switches my tab back to the first one